# Jenkins inside docker how to configure path for hp fortify sourceanalyzer

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I am running my jenkins instance inside docker. 
I am trying to do fortify scan as a post-build step.

I have 
HPE Security Fortify Jenkins Plugin
installed.

Now when I try to do something like

```
def call(String maven_version) {
withMaven(maven: maven_version) {
    script {
        sh "sourceanalyzer -b %JOB_NAME% -jdk 1.7 -extdirs %WORKSPACE%/target/deps/libs/ %WORKSPACE%/target/deps/src/**/* -source target/%JOB_NAME%.fpr"
        }
    }
}
```

But I get

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Fortify Analysis)
[Pipeline] withMaven
[withMaven] Options: []
[withMaven] Available options: 
[withMaven] using JDK installation provided by the build agent
[withMaven] using Maven installation 'Maven 3.3.9'
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Running shell script
+ sourceanalyzer -b %JOB_NAME% -jdk 1.7 -extdirs %WORKSPACE%/target/deps/libs/ %WORKSPACE%/target/deps/src/**/* -source target/%JOB_NAME%.fpr
script.sh: sourceanalyzer: not found"
```

I think all I need to do is create an environment variable for sourceanalyzer, but how do I see where that plugin-is, since this is a docker container and not really an operating system running. Thats where the source of my confusion is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not looking for environment variable.
sourceanalyzer is a executable. and it's not available in the PATH.

Additionally : you can consider docker container as an Operating system (aggregated of multiple things and layers togather before starting.)
If you want to get into RUNNING instance of your JENKIN image then launch following command. (Ensure your container is running).

```
#>docker exec -it <container-id> sh
```

Container id is available when you launch

```
#>docker ps
```

Comment: So, where will I find the installed plugin ? 
And how can I reference it in my dsl ?